# How to access RSA private key at start of an app?

Tags: android, rsa, keystore, private-key

I want to have a `RSA` pair key (private and public key) saved before running so i can send my encrypted message(with public key) and when server gives me a result back, decrypt it using private key.

Obviously i want my private key to be safe from any vulnerability such as exposure. I don't want to generate/store it in Run Time(like using `keystore`). It should exists with application package.

bottom line  i don't want to generate RSA key pairs each time i run my app, because i want to put those in my server too and i want a secure way to store them([there are some ways to extract things](https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend to embed a RSA encryption/decryption keypair in your app because:

- If the key is compromised then the security of your system is affected completely and you will need to distribute a new app to all your users
- The ciphertext size is limited by the key length

To encrypt/decrypt messages between client and server you just need to use a TLS channel (https).

Comment: i want to send user/pass for authentication to server. so it is not very long.

Comment: If you only want to encrypt data sent from client to server, then you just need the public key of the server. Then there was no security risk for including it in your application. But I think using https is a secure and simple solution and allow to encrypt channel in both ways with no size limits

Comment: as you said i thought the same but i couldn't set public key generated in `vb.net` in server to my android application and vice versa. java wanted big integer for modulus and exponent and i can't convert public key xml exported with vb.bet

Comment: What format are you using? Post an example in your question. Java can load a public key from a PEM file, binary DER or using modulus an exponent. Surely the XML can be converted using openssl

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735451/set-modulus-and-exponent-from-vb-net-to-android-java

Comment: Seems you have a valid answer there, so you should be able to load the public key and use it to encrypt