# set Modulus and Exponent from VB.Net to Android/Java

Tags: android, vb.net, rsa, public-key-encryption, modulus

I have this `RSA public key` which is generated in `VB.Net` my server.

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>tv0tzng4pW7erDo2ke/Ku9TGKRukAzx+lihZVblIOE6GWIoiwlILOANeVliZLi1s5qMsXEUA4GV2woC1zFdhJvfFja8Nacl4I3CJ4JYmGqcSZinWKgo3MJdoEqFl9NliF4wTYLow3GYoUh03WxoeArozV1S03drP898b9PdbjPY+ji4jpZHJWnbfg+qWSziF1Q/pSAxpzabeoamz1+ekqlhuxZavQUl+hIhx/quHqy3ybFWcX6yE5NKeY1fzX3L7</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I want to set this value to my android RSA public key but converting with this code doesn't set the key right.

```
RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger("tv0tzng4pW7erDo2ke/Ku9TGKRukAzx+lihZVblIOE6GWIoiwlILOANeVliZLi1s5qMsXEUA4GV2woC1zFdhJvfFja8Nacl4I3CJ4JYmGqcSZinWKgo3MJdoEqFl9NliF4wTYLow3GYoUh03WxoeArozV1S03drP898b9PdbjPY+ji4jpZHJWnbfg+qWSziF1Q/pSAxpzabeoamz1+ekqlhuxZavQUl+hIhx/quHqy3ybFWcX6yE5NKeY1fzX3L7".getBytes())
,new BigInteger("AQAB".getBytes()));
```

EDIT: I tried this code too with no luck.
[image: @Artjom suggestion]

Comment: If the given answer solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) it. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Comment: the problem is the key i used this way doesn't match the one on the server so decryption fails in the way that it doesn't get my plain text.

Comment: i want my Modulus to be exactly what i wrote above but as you can see in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytAaQ.jpg) it is a different key.

Comment: I don't understand. How do you determine that it is different? I see only different encodings of the same modulus. Are you sure, you're using the exact same padding for encryption and decryption?

Comment: i send public key (modulus and exponent) from vb.net in my server which exported into an xml. i want to set my public key to match that.

Comment: Yes and you've done that already. There is not much you can do about that. What your screenshot shows are three different encodings of the same public key data: Base64, Hex and Decimal. If you have trouble with your actual encryption and decryption, perhaps you should ask a question specifically about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140231/discussion-between-mehran-zamani-and-artjom-b).

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to decode the modulus and the exponent from Base64.

Second, you have to use a different constructor for `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude)
```

with `signum` as one, because the both values are not in 2-complement notation and are always positive.

Comment: [android.util.Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html).

Comment: @Artjom B.  Not much clear the answer. What will be the signum value while applying it.

Comment: @S.PSingh `signum` would be `1`

Answer (score 0):

I've written a code to produce a Base64 public key using Modulus and Exponent generated from VB.Net, utilizing JDK 1.8. Please assess its relevance for the intended use case.

```html
byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("F/QOsKgFJE/gMA3j/emq/cVhxNQt4nWmxVWUdV1f9loHq6PK8g2+yRDYwwPmJT2HiafuyE/noJGKlPWNqW2/io6IZbuAvdpZlv4iHQzF/4z6i1wQf/VnFCGQ/ov24sfJgk5ZwqX1CJQcvZJsAmxBB9lEmG95Hx7KAbU=");
byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("AQDB");

BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        
PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);

byte[] publicBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(pubKey.toString().getBytes());
System.out.println("Public Key: " + new String(publicBytes));
```